# Logic errors and syntax errors with inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance

What's wrong with this set of code?  I have errors and I can't find out what's wrong with it. Below is the logic for what I am trying to do. Can someone help me solve this?

`CustNum` says that it's hiding an inherited member and it's saying an error for the `Convert.ToInt32` line and the `new Customer()` method does not work.

```
using System;
public class DebugEight01
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Customer aRegularCustomer = new Customer();
        FrequentCustomer aFrequentCustomer = new Customer(); // I have an error here. 
        aRegularCustomer.CustNum = 2514;
        aRegularCustomer.CustBalance = 765.00;
        aFrequentCustomer.CustNum = 5719;
        aFrequentCustomer.CustBalance = 2500.00;
        aFrequentCustomer.DiscountRate = 0.15;   //15 % 
        Console.WriteLine("\naRegularCustomer #{0} owes {1}",
           aRegularCustomer.CustNum,
           aRegularCustomer.CustBalance = Convert.ToInt32; // I have an error here
        Console.WriteLine("\naFrequentCustomer #{0} would owe {1} without the discount",
           aFrequentCustomer.CustNum,
           aFrequentCustomer.CustBalance.ToString("C2"));
        double newBal = (1 - aFrequentCustomer.DiscountRate) *
           aFrequentCustomer.CustBalance;
        Console.WriteLine("...with {0} discount, customer owes {1}",
           aFrequentCustomer.DiscountRate.ToString("P"), newBal.ToString("C"));
    }
}
public class Customer
{
    private int custNum;
    private double custBalance;
    public int CustNum
    {
        get
        {
            return custNum;
        }
        set
        {
            custNum = value;
        }
    }
    public double CustBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return custBalance;
        }
        set
        {
            CustBalance = value;
        }
    }
}
class FrequentCustomer : Customer
{
    private double discountRate;
    public double DiscountRate
    {
        get
        {
            return discountRate;
        }
        set
        {
            discountRate = value;
        }
    }
    public int CustNum // I have an error here, it's hiding inherited member?
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CustNum;
        }
        set
        {
            CustNum = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding deleting your code: Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are working with classes and inheritance, there are some rules that are applied when you instantiate variables.

If your inheritance tree is something like this

class Object
 + class Customer
     + class FrequentCustomer

If you declare a variable of type `Object` on the right side of the declaration it can take any type that is further down the inheritance tree. This means, it your variable is of type `FrequentCustomer` it has to be assigned an instance of `FrequentCustomer` only. If it's of type `Customer` then it can take both `Customer` and `FrequentCustomer` and so on. All classes inherit the type `object`, which is why I added it to the inheritance tree.
The following are all valid declarations.

```
object c = new Customer();
object c = new FrequesntCustomer();
Customer c = new Customer();
Customer c = new FequentCustomer();
FrequentCustomer c = new FrequentCustomer();
```

This is where why your first compile error occurs.

Second error is because you are using the `Convert.ToInt32()` method incorrectly. The correct syntax is

```
Console.WriteLine("\naRegularCustomer #{0} owes {1}",
       aRegularCustomer.CustNum,
       Convert.ToInt32(aRegularCustomer.CustBalance)); // im having a error here
```

Your third error is not an error, but a warning only. The class `FrequentCustomer` already has the properties from `Customer` inherited, even though you haven't specified them explicitly. This means, that you don't need to specify the propert `CustNum` in the `FrequentCustomer` class, it already had it inherited. However, if for some reason you need to add the property (because for example it has different implementation that his parent class), then you need to add the keyword `new` on the property like this:

```
public new int CustNum
{
    get
    {
        return base.CustNum;
    }
    set
    {
        CustNum = value;
    }
}
```

If you don't do this, this will be done automatically (hiding inherited member), but you will get a warning about it.

Comment: I edited the answer. Put it at the end. `Console.WriteLine("\naRegularCustomer #{0} owes {1}",
           aRegularCustomer.CustNum,
           Convert.ToInt32(aRegularCustomer.CustBalance));`

Comment: DiscountRate is a property of the class `FrequentCustomer` therefore your variable must be of type `FrequentCustomer` delcared on the left side. `FrequentCustomer cust = new FrequentCustomer()` like this.

Comment: There's chat here on StackOverflow. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6367/alexanders-homework

Answer (score 1):

`CustNum` in the parent class needs to be marked `virtual`.

Your second error is a lack of a closing bracket, and the fact that you aren't actually supplying `Convert.ToInt32` with a parameter (i.e. something to convert).

Answer (score 1):

First of all it not error (im having a error here, its hiding inherited member?). Its warning. No need to redefine `CustNum` property in sub-class. That way you are hiding base class memeber.

Error at - `FrequentCustomer aFrequentCustomer = new Customer();` and it must be,

```
FrequentCustomer aFrequentCustomer = new FrequentCustomer ();
```

Error at - `CustBalance` property in Customer class

```
 public double CustBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return custBalance;
        }
        set
        {
            // CustBalance = value; <-- It will assign value to property not a field
            //                          will cause StackOverflow
            custBalance=value;                          
        }
    }
```

And no need to convert while you are printing/writing them as string.

```
 Console.WriteLine("\naRegularCustomer #{0} owes {1}",
           aRegularCustomer.CustNum,
           aRegularCustomer.CustBalance);
```

For better practice always use _ (underscore) as first char of field or use `Auto-Implemented properties.`

```
public class Customer
{
    private int _custNum;
    private double _custBalance;
    public int CustNum
    {
        get
        {
            return _custNum;
        }
        set
        {
            _custNum = value;
        }
    }
   .....
}
```

Auto-Implemented properties:

```
public class Customer
{
  public int CustNum {get;set;}
  public double CustBalance {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Hiding Inherited members,
  Customer is a base class and it already has a property CustNum 
  so there is no need to specify this on FrequentCustomer unless you want to Override this

```
   FrequentCustomer aFrequentCustomer = new Customer(); // im having a error here. 

   Customer aFrequentCustomer = new FrequentCustomer();
```

First statement will not work, it actually goes the other way around.
The second statement will work.
If you really want to do it this way, you could consider using interface like ICustomer

Answer (score 0):

What the 'inherited member' message means is that the CustNum property of the Customer class is no longer accessible from the FrequentCutomer class. It doesn't recognize that they are supposed to be the same property. You need to tell it that by marking the one in Customer as `virtual` as in `public virtual int CustNum`. You mark the one in FrequentCustomer as `override` as in `public override int CustNum`. In this case, the property could be eliminated from the FrequentCustomer class, as it is just redundant.

I think you meant `Convert.ToInt32(aRegularCustomer.CustBalance)`. Though personally, I never use Convert. I would normally use `(int)aRegularCustomer.CustBalance`, but this is just my preference.

Instead of `new Customer()` you want `new FrequentCustomer()`. You can't put a `Customer` into a `FrequentCustomer` variable, because it isn't one.

One more thing, you meant `custBalance = value;` in your `CustBalance` property. Otherwise, setting the property generates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to the linbe:

```
     FrequentCustomer aFrequentCustomer = new Customer(); // im having a error here.
```

It is causing an error because you are trying to store a reference to an object in a variable that is declared to be of a type which is dervived from the concrete type of the object (on the right side).   This is like creating an object of type Mammal, and attempting to call it a pig.  It's ok to create a Pig and call it a Mammal, but it's not ok to create a Mammal and call it  a pig.